# Where is the location of Microsoft Edge Extension Folder that are installed on MacOS?

Tags: macos, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to locate the folder that contains the installed extensions for Microsoft Edge **macOS** but do not know where the folder is. I have extension developer mode enabled so I can see the extension ID plus it also allows me to pack extensions. While these features are useful this still does not help me where the ["Extension root directory"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuECM.png) is and since I don't know where it is, I cannot proceed.

If there is anyone with experience for Microsoft Edge extensions for MacOS it would help me out gratefully. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to know the path of the profile you use. You can find it in `edge://version` like below:

[image]

In the picture, we use the *Default* profile, the profile folder name is *Default*. The extensions you install is under the path: */Users/username/Library/Application Support/Microsoft Edge/profilefolder/Extensions*.